# Change a <td> color background with "php if" in html

Tags: php, html, css

I'm finishing a homework, but there is something bothering me, which is the fact that I cant change a `<td></td>` background color using php.

This is a code from html using some classes of php and all that stuff

```
<?php
<td 
<?php
if ($produtos->dtfora==1001-01-01) {
    echo "style="; background-color;darkred;"";
}
?>
>
<?php echo $produtos->dtfora; ?>
</td>
```

There are no error messages, it just doesn't work or change anything

Comment: You opened the PHP tag twice!

Comment: Are you sure your CSS syntax is correct? In your post`background-color;darkred` is not, it should be `background-color: darkred`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must do it like this :

```
<?php $style = 'background-color:darkred'; ?>

<td style="<?php echo $style ?>">
    // Your Content
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple small issues with this.
First, there are two opening `php` tags. Fixing this would turn the code into the following:

```
<td 
<?php
    if ($produtos->dtfora=="1001-01-01") {
        echo 'style="; background-color;darkred;"';
    }
?>
>
<?php echo $produtos->dtfora; ?>
</td>
```

This is still not easy to read or easy to maintain, so moving the result of the statement into a seperate variable would be ideal:

```
<?php
    // Define default style
    $style = "";
    // If the statement is matched, set the style variable to the custom color
    if ($produtos->dtfora=="1001-01-01") {
        $style = "background-color: darkred;";
    }
?>

<!-- Use the style variable, either empty or filled with color into the style attribute of the td -->
<td style="<?php echo $style; ?>">
    <?php echo $produtos->dtfora; ?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$changeBg = "background-color:red";

?>

<td style="<?php echo $changeBg ?>">
   Email ID
<td>
```

Comment: Please add at least some explanation as though why this answer the question

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below.

```
<?php
if ($produtos->dtfora=="1001-01-01") {
    echo "style='background-color:darkred";
}
```

Comment: Please add at least some explanation as though why this answer the question

Answer (score 0):

for this you can simple using a class for this and add this class according to your condition. example:

```
<style>
.productos_td: {background-color:darkred;}
</style>
<?php
if ($produtos->dtfora==1001-01-01) { ?>
<td class="productos_td">
<?php } else{ ?> <td> <?php } ?>
</td>
```